# how to find out why the process is sleeping/blocked in linux

Tags: android, linux, process

friends:

some time we found our program run abnormally, that is, it is not crashed, but did not running as we expected, it is SLEEPING!

then, i want to find out why it is SLEEPING, such as, some socket reading blocked? some signal waiting blocked? or other things occurred to block this process.

HOW to DO? i find the ps or the /proc/pid/stats only can indicate its states and its signal mask. BUT i want to know more detail, which socket,signal or other things blocked it?

anyone can give some help information?

it is in linux/android, the process is common process, native or java process.

thx a lot in advance

Comment: The main thread of a normal Android process should usually be blocked somewhere in the platform code, since it is supposed to be event-driven, and would only call into your code to deliver an event.  Some other thread you create should run, unless you make blocking calls, or Android kills your process.  If it does that, it may later re-create it, but without necessarily causing your thread to be recreated (depending on where in your program you do that).

Answer (score 1):

If your process is blocked on a system call, you can use `strace` to find out what it is. Note that the `strace` binary may not be installed on your android system, but there is a version of it in recent versions of `busybox`. Also you may need root access, so you'll want to jailbreak your android device.

Here's a contrived example.

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/foo
$ cat /tmp/foo &       # blocks
$ ps                   # note pid of the blocked "cat" process; in my case it's 29739
$ sudo strace -p 29739 # attach to the process
```

The output of strace in this case is:

```
Process 29739 attached - interrupt to quit
open("/tmp/foo", O_RDONLY^C <unfinished ...>
```

strace will then hang along with your process; hit ctrl-c to break.

Here's another example:

```
$ nc -l  8888 &
[2] 31087
$ sudo strace -p 31087
Process 31087 attached - interrupt to quit
accept(3,
```

In this case you might want to know what it's trying to `accept`; you can use the /proc filesystem for this:

```
$ ls -l /proc/31087/fd/3
lrwx------ 1 abliss abliss 64 Jun 25 12:22 /proc/31087/fd/3 -> socket:[2265625]
```

If your process is blocked in a java thread, you'll probably have better luck using the android tools to attach a debugger like `jdb`.

Comment: You do *not* need root access.  It may be easier to fire up the ndk gdb though, as there are instructions for that.